# C# Wait for pending IO operations

Tags: c#, io, filesystemwatcher

Given a directory, how can I wait until it has no pending IO operations (with an optional timeout).

- I might be copying, moving or deleting many files.
- If one operation fails, they all need to be reversed.
- Some operations are dependent on others (E.G When deleting a file,
  create the backup directory, move the file)

E.G

```
string targetParentDirectory = "C:\\mydir";
int timeOut = 500;

//Do many IO operations in targetParentDirectory

WaitForPendingOperations(targetParentDirectory, timeOut);

//Continue main thread
```

I can use the one FileSystemWatcher per operation I guess.

- Watching for each individual operation is very slow.
- Watching for all operations at the same time is problematic when
  having a timeout (starting every thread, making sure the thread is
  active, having a large enough timeout to wait for all of this plus the actual file operation...)

Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you doing all those IO operations concurrently? Based on your question, it seems you might be spawning a thread for each op. If so, why couldn't you just join on all the threads?

Comment: No, I copy, move & delete all on the main thread. Regardless, the issue remains that the IO does not happen immediately. If I delete a folder then check if it exists immediately, it will return true most of the time.

Comment: If you did it all in separate threads, each thread could just use a filesystemwatcher for its specific action and it would be easy to join on all the threads completing.

Comment: Most of the operations need to be done in a specific order unfortunately.
E.G 
For deleting a file... create backup dir, move file.

Comment: That seems to contradict your question. If operations must be done sequentially then you must wait on individual operations.

Comment: Ah, I see your edit. In that case, it appears that DeleteFile becomes a thread and in it you sequence all the necessary file system operations where you wait on each individual one. Then you join on all the DeleteFile threads. No?

Comment: I was hoping there was a more efficient way. Is there no function that returns pending operations in a sub directory? Otherwise for every IO operation or group of IO operations I need to create extra functionality to run them on a separate thread, watch for each change then join all threads at the end.

Comment: Another thing, all these IO operations are part of a method that runs them sequentially. This method is atomic. If one IO operation fails, it must revert changes made.

Comment: A more efficient way? What you're suggesting is horribly inefficient. So the filesystem would need to log and track every independent file change for all directories and keep track of whether they were pending for every directory that could exist.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to your described problem:

1. Aggregate file system operations that must occur together, either sequentially (perhaps w/ rollback on failure) or can be done independently into threads.
2. Each thread handles performing items in sequence, waiting for completion, and any rollback necessary (with timeouts so they don't wait forever).
3. Join on the thread completion.

This is a trivial amount of change (and extra code beyond what you already have). There aren't that many file operations you could be performing. In fact, you only need to write one "thread" or worker class.

Even if you had a combinatoric number of different possible file io sequences, then the worker constructor should instead take an object that represents the sequence of operations and be able to dispatch them as needed. Help solving that kind of problem belongs in another question.

Comment: How would I solve the performance issue of if one file IO operation fails, all threads need to be stopped and reversed? Or wait until they finish then reverse.

Comment: You need to rethink your design. What if you have 40 operations. 20 run to completion, one fails, the others are partway done. You'd need to undo the 20 partway done (19 + the one that failed), and completely reverse the 20 that finished.

Your design has the performance issues. Once you remove the performance issues from your system architecture, then you can worry about whether you've introduced performance issues in the code to implement it.

Comment: @BenY (See also the previous comment, forgot to tag you) If you can't change from the all-or-nothing approach, then you'd need to design your procedures so that you can sends threads a signal to "reverse" operation and can start finished jobs in "reverse" mode. That would save you having to wait for all threads to run to completion. Aside from that, there's nothing you can do short of reworking the design to save further on performance due to carrying out the reverse-if-one-fails requirement.